# Declare variable in eval Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, eval

There is a way to declare variable in eval ? For example

```
function test
{
   eval $1
}

 test "
       value="foo"
       echo "$value"
       "
```

But it display nothing.
Anyone can help please ?

Comment: Maybe try replacing your `test` with `foobar` first, and then replace the function call's `foobar` with `echo` to get some insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes don't nest.

Use `set -xv` to see what the shell is actually running.

Fixed code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function Test() {
   eval "$1"
}

Test 'value=foo
      echo $value'
```

Note that the parameter to `eval` is double quoted. You can use it without quotes, but then you need to insert a semicolon before the `echo`.

Single quotes are needed in the parameter, if you want double quotes, you have to escape (backslash) the dollar sign, otherwise the variable would be expanded before the string is passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination sir

Comment: @RevOneX9 if this solved your problem then you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)